# I can't get my angular ui-router nested states to work. Code inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I literally tried anything at this point, but I am still learning and can't get this to work.
https://plnkr.co/edit/FrNChlSwHYDbapr7gFQH?p=preview

```
<a class="collection-item" 
    ng-repeat="task in tasks"
    ui-sref="todo.detail({ todoID: task.todoID })">
    {{ task.text }}
</a>
```

What I am trying to do, is routing to /todo/1, /todo/2 and so on from the "todo"-view, but I seem to have a problem with the $stateParams.
It'd be nice if you guys could help me out and show me where my problem is :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to adding an id field to your task objects you will need to put a `<section ui-view></section>` in your todo.html file. This is how nested states work. You can use an href as Oliver mentioned or stick to the sref. I've forked your plunk [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/aHgABXdQZukLXBHiFvpI) as an example.

Comment: Thanks, your additions to my code were especially helpful!

Comment: No problem.. glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each task in your array of tasks has an `ID` you want to then navigate to you're going to need something along the lines of:

```
<a class="collection-item" 
    ng-repeat="task in tasks"
    ng-href="#todo/{{ task.todoID }}">
    {{ task.text }}
</a>
```

You'll then need the `/todo/:toDoId` or something similar set up in your routes.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `todoID` in your `tasks` items.

This works: https://plnkr.co/edit/Wk33w2eRfpz7UZNNZzFs?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, I did not know I actually had to do that.